# Diagonalisable matrices question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image: question]

Hello, I am puzzling through this for homework. I understand most of the theory here, but I'm struggling to put together a coherent proof. I can easily see that (b) follows from what is shown in (a) by matrix multiplication applied to both sides, but I would appreciate hints on how to achieve (a).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand that $$AC=A\left[\text{Col}_1(C)\mid \ldots \mid \text{Col}_n(C) \right]=\left[A\text{Col}_1(C)\mid \ldots \mid A\text{Col}_n(C) \right]?$$

Comment: @GitGud I'm afraid not, 'Col' is new to me

Comment: It's just a suggestive notation to denote the $i^{\text{th}}$ column. Do you get it after knowing this?

Comment: @GitGud Sure, I think I can follow that notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\begin{align} AC&=A\left[\text{Col}_1(C)\mid \ldots \mid \text{Col}_n(C) \right]\\ &=\begin{bmatrix}A\text{Col}_1(C)\mid \ldots \mid A\text{Col}_n(C) \end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}Av_1\mid \ldots \mid Av_n \end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}\lambda _1v_1\mid \ldots \mid \lambda _nv_n \end{bmatrix}\\
&=C\Lambda. \end{align}$$