# Prove that $A$ diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix, and let $v_1,...,v_n$ be a basis of $R^n$ so that each $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$. Prove that $A$ diagonalizable.

Does the diagonalization of $A = QDQ^{-1}$ anything to do with this?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hint: Use a change of basis to write $A$ in the basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$.

Comment: Tempted to close as a duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732421/diagonalisable-matrices-question/732435#732435).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Characterization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagonalization theorem states that for an $n \times n$ matrix to be diagonalizable, the matrix must have $n$ *linearly independent* eigenvectors to form the matrix $Q$.  In your case, there are $n$ distinct eigenvectors ($v_1,...,v_n$).  Furthermore, the fact that they form a *basis* indicates that they are linearly independent (by the definition of a basis).  Therefore, we have shown that the conditions given meet the requirement to be a diagonalizable matrix.